How can I change an email template variable to show the Customer Group Name instead of the ID number
I have created an observer to grab the customer group ID and create a variable that can be added to my email template as shown below. 
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class AddCustomerGroupToOrderEmail implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_order;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order
    ) {
        $this->_order = $order;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $customerGroupId = $order->getCustomerGroupId();

        // You can do additional processing with the customer group if needed.

        $order->setData('customer_group_id', $customerGroupId);
    }
}

Then In my email template, I can include 
{{var order.customer_group_id}}

 to display the customer group ID.
I would like to know if I can make the Variable to show the customer group NAME instead of the ID number,
So that my employees don't all need to remember what every number means.
For example,
if customerGroupId = 0, then it would say Not Logged In,
if customerGroupId = 1, then it would say General. 
I don't know PHP very well and have just started using Magento so if anyone can help, I'd appreciate it.
Thanks.

what is the name of the email template? if the email tempalate is custom how are you defining it? Second, where are you handling the transaction i.e the send? because all you are doing is setting the "customer_group_id" to the order data. But are doing absolutely nothing to the email template or variables.

There is still a lot of missing information.
For example: is this email template custom or core?
if its custom, how are you defining the email template and how are you handling the sending logic of this email (as this is where the setting up of email variables lives).
if its core code then then what is the name of the email template you are trying to use (as this will tell us what send class we will be looking at)
However, for this example we will be using Magento_Sales::Template class. We will be doing a Before Plugin (best practice).
Path of File: vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Email/Container/Template.php
Function to Motify: setTemplateVars(array $vars)
STEP 1 create plugin class. app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/Plugin/OrderEmailContainerTemplatePlugin.php
<?php
namespace YourVendor\YourModule\Plugin;

use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\Template;

class OrderEmailContainerTemplatePlugin
{
    /**
     * Before plugin for setTemplateVars
     *
     * @param Template $subject
     * @param void $result
     * @param array $vars
     * @return void
     */
    public function beforeSetTemplateVars(Template $subject, array $vars)
    {
        // Your custom logic goes here
        // For example, here is where you want to get the Customer Group Name the template variables

        // here you want to add the customer Group Name to the $vars array.
        $vars['order_data']['customer_group_name'] = <customer group name>

        return $vars;
    }
}

STEP 2 define plugin.
app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/etc/di.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\Template">
        <plugin name="order_email_container_template_plugin"
                type="YourVendor\YourModule\Plugin\OrderEmailContainerTemplatePlugin" />
    </type>
</config>

STEP 3 Run setup upgrade.
From here you should be able to ge the group id by calling order_data.customer_group_name
I trust you know how to add custom modules and enable them as well as the commands for running the setup upgrade.

You can fetch customer group names using ID with the help of Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface repository.
See the updated code below :
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class AddCustomerGroupToOrderEmail implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order
     */
    protected $_order;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $groupRepository;

    /**
     * AddCustomerGroupToOrderEmail constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface $groupRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface $groupRepository
    ) {
        $this->_order = $order;
        $this->groupRepository = $groupRepository;
    }

    /**
     * Executes the observer.
     *
     * @param Observer $observer The observer object.
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $customerGroupId = $order->getCustomerGroupId();

        $customerGroupName = $this->getGroupName($customerGroupId);

        // You can do additional processing with the customer group if needed.

        $order->setData('customer_group_id', $customerGroupId);
        $order->setData('customer_group_name', $customerGroupName);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the name of the customer group.
     *
     * @param int $groupId The ID of the customer group.
     * @return string The name of the customer group.
     */
    public function getGroupName($groupId) {
        $group = $this->groupRepository->getById($groupId);
        return $group->getCode();
    }
}

It uses the getGroupName method to get the name of the customer group based on the group ID:
$customerGroupName = $this->getGroupName($customerGroupId);

Then I set, the customer group name in the order data.
$order->setData('customer_group_name', $customerGroupName);

Thanks!

So which file do I use to "set the customer group name in the order data."

please check my answer's Observer file, I have set data inside it.

Hi Jigar, I've copied your code and pasted into my observer file and updated the Vendor/Module namespace.  I still have {{var order.customer_group_name}} {{var order.customer_group_id}} {{if order.customer_group_id == 1}} General{{/if}}
{{if order.customer_group_id == 2}} Wholesale{{/if}} in my email template. The only variable showing up in the email still is the order.customer.group.id, not the name.  Do I need to run any commands to update the module after making the change to make this work?  It is a live store.
